# Combining fields in Awk

Tags: awk

is there an easy away to combine fields in awk? Specifically, I have lines like this:

```
1,2,some text
3,4,some text, but it has commas in it, annoyingly
```

I want to extract the two numbers as the first two fields, but then I want all of the text (commas and all) to be the third field. Is there a way to do that?

My basic awk call was like this:

```
awk -F\, '{print $1"|"$2"|"$3}' file.txt
```

Which works fine for the first line, but stops at the comma in the text on the second line.

Comment: The answers provided below will work. But if you can, in your example you should better use a format like tsv. This way you would not mix field content and field separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
awk '{for (i=0;i<2;i++) sub(",", "|", $0); print}' file.txt
```

Comment: De nada. It's not exactly what you asked for, but it does the job. =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed to do it.

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/\(.?*\),\(.?*\),/\1|\2|/'
```